# Dual Boot, Upgraded to windows 11 and firmware and now i can not boot into ubuntu GUI

Tags: nvidia, gui, xps

So here is the situation. I have a dell xps 15 9510. Dual boot and spend most of my time in ubuntu. So much time in fact its been months since i booted into windows. I boot into windows yesterday and i have a slew of updates. Namely, windows 11 update, nvidia update, and a firmware update. I click accept w/e. Windows 11 loads after an hour of doing its thing. Today i wanted to boot back into linux. Now i get the black screen with cursor. ctrl + alt + f4 brings up terminal.

I vaguely recall going through this before and it had something to do with my eufi and secure boot. so i went into my bios and disabled all the security settings to no avail. Ill take any ideas!!

Comment: Windows or Dell update to UEFI resets to defaults. I had to keep a list for my older systems, but new system even boots with Secure Boot on, but has no proprietary (nVidia or WiFi) driver. Windows 11 may have bitlocker and has fast start up which must be turned off. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Thanks! I solved this problem by re-installing an older version of my firmware and disabling all the secure boot. then changed over to lightdm as my graphics. God was it painful. Morale of the story is to never update.

Comment: Dell, Windows & now Linux with fwupdate will all want to update firmware if system in fwupdate device list. UEFI/BIOS updates brand model list  for Dell with (uefi >= 0.6.2 & dell >= 0.7.3) 
https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist  Or good backups are important.